# How to get HTTP status code from RNWebView

Tags: typescript, react-native, webview

I'm working on React-Native/TypeScript App for iOS and Android.

After finishing load the webpage (RNWebView), I need HTTP response code.

As NavState don't support this, I'm thinking to use injected JavaScript to find somehow status code.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the HTTP status code of loaded webpage at all.

NOTE: if any webresource/webpage fails to load, it is possible to get that error code and for that you'll have to use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview